# Runtime.HandlerNotFound :: Node js 14 :: AWS LAMBDA

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless, aws-serverless

My runtime setting indicates "index.handler" as the "Handler" to be called,
But getting this error.
Where am I going wrong?[enter image description here][1]

**Execution result:**

```
test

Response
{
  "errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
  "errorMessage": "index.handler is undefined or not exported",
  "trace": [
    "Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported",
    "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)",
    "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)",
    "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)",
    "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)",
    "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)",
    "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)",
    "    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)",
    "    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"
  ]
}

Function Logs
START RequestId: 7dca2129-ebb8-4241-969f-91b7c3c4a08c Version: $LATEST
2021-05-22T16:24:17.126Z    undefined   ERROR   Uncaught Exception  {"errorType":"Runtime.HandlerNotFound","errorMessage":"index.handler is undefined or not exported","stack":["Runtime.HandlerNotFound: index.handler is undefined or not exported","    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:144:11)","    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:43:30)","    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)","    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)","    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)","    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)","    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)","    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47"]}
2021-05-22T16:24:17.145Z    undefined   ERROR   (node:9) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'handler' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

**index.js :**

```
exports.handler =  async function(event, context) {
  console.log("Hello ...");
  return "hey";
}
```

**image of runtime setting:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGeO3.png

Comment: You tried hitting from the aws console or the cli?

Comment: I tried running the same code by creating a lambda from my end and is working absolutely fine.

Comment: Can you share your serverless.yaml file?

Comment: @CássioLacerda thanks for the input, but if you are talking about the serverless framework, I am not using any framework.

Comment: @RohithJoseph I am using aws console.

Comment: Yes, I thought you would use. Sorry!

Comment: @RohithJoseph exactly there is no problem in code.
What are your runtime settings?
Handler -> index.handler ?

Comment: Yes. It is. Can you try creating a new lambda with the same and run it once and check? because the same code is working for me

Comment: Also I used the editor given in the lambda console and did not touch any settings.

Comment: WOw...
@RohithJoseph ***it worked***...

Reason It did not work last time:
I choose java 11 primarily then after realizing that ide is not provided for java 11 I switched ***same lambda function*** runtime setting to node js, modified handler, and directory structure it was exactly the same as the new working one.  

just tried java 11 to node Again switch still did not work.

Well Thanks

Comment: Great. Good to know